# How to show list of email sharing options without using an Intent and chooser?

Tags: android, list, show, sharing

I want my Android app to show a chooser when the user clicks on a email address from my application without adding code to start a chooser via `Intent`.

What do I need to include in my `TextView` to do this?

Comment: what do you mean 'without adding code startactivity(Intent.cratechooser)' ? Usually you have to write code to add features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add an `Intent` to create a chooser then you can just make the contents of the `TextView` a mailto link.  Here's an example:

strings.xml value

```
<string name="email_address">&lt;a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com&lt;/a></string>
```

The code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email_address);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.email_address)));
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This will open up a list of mail clients available for sharing via email.  There is one stipulation however, if the user only has one mail client setup or has a default client set then the list won't appear, it'll just open up the default mail client.

If you want to add things like attachments, a subject, or default message then you need to create the appropriate mailto link to accomplish that.  This example only opens the client with the "to" field filled out.

Comment: Thanks... this works for me to show default sharing list...
Can u tell me how can i pass the subject and body with the same?

Comment: You'd have to add the subject and body parameters to the link. `mailto:example@example.com?subject=Hello&body=Ahoy%20sir!` If you have more questions about that, it'd be best to ask a new question instead of adding more requirements to this one. Also, don't forget to click the check mark to accept this answer if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

A sharing list is created using the intent ACTION_SEND :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/).